# How to use latex in matplotlib within anaconda3 on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: matplotlib, latex

I've been working with Ubuntu 20.04 on VMware virtual machines for a long time. This question has puzzled me for a long time and how to use LaTeX in Matplotlib is unclear on the official website. I hope a clear (and if possible, simple) solution to this question.
What's more, how to find font files in my virtual machine? I have download texlive2021, but even I put latex, dvipng and ghostscript on anaconda3/bin, it still told me that there was no cmss10 font file, and I can't understand the reason. If possible, please tell me the reason and solve this question. Thanks!

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example of your LaTeX code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.